# Making div dragable after being inserted from database

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Wondered if anyone could help me out with this jquery ui drag/drop issue.

I have some draggable and droppable divs that clone themselves when they are dragged over to there container. I am saving the position of the div's in a database, however if I insert the exact same HTML dynamicly and reload the page the div is no longer draggable, droppable etc.

I understand that its because the jQuery is no longer bound to the div...?

So my question, how can I enable the dynamicly inserted div's to be draggable/droppable again?

I did try and implement LiveQuery but could not get it working, how would I use .live?

Here's a URL to the page (link went dead) all the drag/drop etc JS is in custom.js

Any help is really appreciated

Many thanks

EDIT: Anyone have any ideas? I really am stuck on this one :(

Comment: This website looks lovely by the way.  The leaf buttons could do with being graphical mind, but otherwise excellent; I like genealogy and first did a lot when I was 10, very long ago.  I would have loved something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to call `draggable()` on the items that are in your tree.  Your existing code does this already for all items having the class `drag`.

From your code ('custom.js'):

```
//Make element draggable
$(".drag").draggable( ... );
```

This doesn't affect the items in your tree, because they don't have the class `drag`.  An easy fix would be to simply add the class `drag` to your tree items. Alternately, you could specifically select your tree items somehow, and then apply draggable to that selection.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that's got it sorted now :)